# Get bibtex key from helm-bibtex

Tags: string, helm-bibtex

I would like to get the bibtex key of references in my `.bib` database as a string via `helm-bibtex`.

```elisp
(defun get-bibtex-key ()
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (helm-bibtex)
    (if (string-prefix-p "cite" (buffer-string))
        (substring (buffer-string) 5) ;; Remove "cite: " from string.
      (buffer-string))
    (buffer-string)))
```

The code above correctly returns the desired value, but inserts text into the current buffer instead of storing its value within the `get-bibtex-key` function-variable as a string, which makes further deployment such as this impossible:

```elisp
(bibtex-completion-get-entry (get-bibtex-key))
```

The above code when run just dumps the value returned by `(get-bibtex-key)` into the current buffer.

How can I get output from `(helm-bibtex)` behave like the code below?

```elisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "Hi!")
  (buffer-string))
```

Comment: Other approaches (such as ready-made functions) to getting bibtex key from a `.bib` database would also be appreciated.

Comment: See `bibtex-map-entries`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the keys using `helm-marked-candidates`:

```
(defun get-bibtex-key (_)
  (let ((keys (helm-marked-candidates)))
    (print keys)))

(helm-add-action-to-source "Get bibtex keys" 'get-bibtex-key helm-source-bibtex 0)
```

Then:

1. `M-x helm-bibtex`
2. `M-a`
3. `RET`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use the `(bibtex-completion-candidates)` function, which returns a list of bibtex items. You then get the list containing the "=key=" string using `assoc`, taking the `cdr` (last) element of the alist which is the citation key. Finally pass this list of keys through `completing-read` so you can select one from the list, returning it as a string:

```
(defun get-bibtex-key ()
  (interactive)
  (completing-read "Citation key: "
                  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cdr (assoc "=key=" x)))
                          (bibtex-completion-candidates))))
```

Comment: Can a search be done on the author-title instead, like what we would do in helm?